# Stream Webcam MJPEG feed as RTSP without transcoding

Tags: streaming, debian, rtsp, ip-camera, mjpeg

I'am using a Microsoft LifeCam Studio USB CAM on a tiny Debian box called Pogoplug.
On it runs MJPG-Streamer which takes the raw MJPEG stream from the cam and make it available via HTTP which works perfectly fine with about 20% CPU usage.
Now I want to use a new software to process the video stream on a more powerful server but it only work with RTSP.
The maintainer of MJPG-Streamer started a plugin to output RTSP, however for me it's simply not working even with the experimental branch (just do nothing).
After hours playing around with avconv/avserver I still found no solution to just grep the raw MJPEG stream and put it into a RTSP stream without doing anything, no transcoding, nothing.
Does someone know an easy and painless way to do this?